# Use RSS from Bitrix

Tags: rss, bitrix

I'd like to use rss channel from website https://www.staraya-moneta.ru/forum/. For example https://www.staraya-moneta.ru/forum/rss/default/forum/67/.
All works fine. But sometimes I download html-file instead of rss-file.
Can you help me, please, to solve the problem?
[Screenshot of html-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkRhc.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I try to download rss by the following cmd:

```
curl -XGET -H "Accept: */*" https://www.staraya-moneta.ru/forum/rss/rss2/forum/57/
```

I see the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I try to download from browser from "Private session"

```
Result the same
```

I update page and I get the correct result - rss file

I try to add PHPSESSID and BX_USER_ID to download, but it works only sometimes.